# why the validation accuracy does not increase in a normal way over the epochs?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to transfer learning VGG16 model with imagenet in a dataset of retinal images but i'm confused to get a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l5Wf.png), I don't know why the validation accuracy didn't increase in a normal way over the epochs, like training accuracy did, is it an index of overfitting ? if yes, how can i overcome it ?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use a ResNet (network that contains residual connections) as a first step towards the improvement, in order to avoid the vanishing gradient problem.

VGGs have become less used are no longer relevant for benchmarking. What you should use instead is a ResNet50, which is available in `tensorflow.keras.applications` alongside other relevant pre-trained neural networks.

Also, the validation accuracy fluctuates very much; in addition to the previously mentioned possible improvement, you may want to recheck the construction of your training and validation sets.

Comment: I have the same problem with ResNet 50 and with a lower accuracy than VGG 16

Comment: Then your problems comes from the way you constructed your dataset altogether; either there is a problem in the validation set, either you have too few samples. How many samples do you have altogether? What is the balance of the data?

Comment: I have a dataset which is scattered, I have a file which contains two experiments of OCT on mice, each experiment is divided on 4 days 0, 2, 7, 14. in each day we have a set of files for each eye of mouse, and for each eye we have a file which contains 512 images (each image is a layer of same image) of size 1024 * 512.

Comment: i'm trying to classify the images to detect the disease that appeared from day 7, so I started with 2 classes, day 0 and 14, I took the pictures from day 0 of all the mice and day 14 then I split these images for train and test files, I gave the train file 75% of the images and 25% in the test.
I have 25,600 images for training, and 8704 for the test.